# How to use template property in Facebook Instant Game SDK

Tags: facebook-instant-games

reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart

```
FBInstant.updateAsync({
  action:
  cta:
  image:
  text:
  template: 'this property',
  data:
  strategy:
  notification:
})
```

I know this property is relative with app config (fbapp-config.json).
but I don't know how to use this property exactly. 'text' and 'template' are same thing?

Does anyone have an easier example?

ps. sorry for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention of the template is to categorize different messages. E.g. if you send a message for a new high score, you could use a `'HIGH_SCORE'` template. If you had a different message for a gift, you could use a `'SEND_GIFT'` template. The analytics for these templates are broken out in Facebook Analytics for analysis.

It is not required to use a different template for different messages today, but it is recommended.